# Scroll event doesn't fire properly after scrollbar disappered on IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem on scroll event.
It doesn't fire properly after scrollbar disappered on IE (tested on IE 9)

demo(console required):
http://jsbin.com/AJiQoFA/1/

On chrome, it fire scroll event if I remove the added content.
Note that we should scroll a bit or It doesn't trigger too.

Comment: Can you specify the IE version, IE 11 seems to work (as far as I get it)

Comment: @Stefan I tested on ie 9 as I mentioned...